# Использование обратного отсчета в ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, функции, ng-repeat, countdown

Всем вновь привет.

Есть таблица, в ней есть столбики с разными данными.. два из этих столбика - даты, дата начала и дата окончания (условно).

Хочу прикрутить к ним плагин обратного отсчета.. Какой-нибудь простой без выкрутасов ... Нашел вот такой: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Никак на ночь глядя не соображу как можно заставить вызваться функцию на каждой строчке с параметром даты...

p.s. Думаю из названия понятно, что таблицу рисую через NG-REPEAT...

Answer (score 0):

1) Написать директиву, которая будет запускать отсчёт

2) Данную директиву добавить к элементу с датой